# Python timeit ImportError

Tags: python, timeit

I am trying to compute the time my program takes to execute but sometimes it works fine and sometimes I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'N' from '__main__'
```

```
    N = number 

    t = timeit.Timer(
    "computeArea(N, 4)",
    "from __main__ import computeArea, N")        
    computeTime = t.timeit(1)

    print(computeTime)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think of just importing `time` and measuring the time before and after `computeArea`  runs? Honestly speaking, this chunk of code looks pretty funky from a Python style perspective. Measuring the time yourself is easy, and can be easily modified for more interesting examples (say, taking the average time by timing the same code dozens of times).

```py
import time

start_time = time.time()

# Do anything here. This is a filler.
for i in range(100):
  print(i)

end_time = time.time()
total_time = end_time - start_time

print(f"Program took {total_time} seconds.")
```

Comment: The thing is I have to use this particular piece of code. Is there any solution to fix the error on my code? Thank you.